# Error: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am working on a project which is using MPEG2 codec for decoding of a video. My codec is in C.

After decoding a video it is returning unsigned char pointer of RGB buffer which is a pointer to an image bits which are stored as an byte Array. My display function is in Android, so I have to send that information to Android using JNI.

Before calling to display function I have copied that RGB buffer data in to byte Array and pass it to display function:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = false;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,   data.length,opt);
canvas.drawBitmap(bit, draw_x, draw_y, null);
```

But when I am running the application the message is coming:

> DEBUG/skia(327):SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

I don't know why bitmapFactory is returning null. Since I am beginner with Android, I don't know too much about Android programming. Can anybody please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved this error. What I have done I have added bitmap header before the RGB data and then copied that data into byte array and then pass it to the display function which is in android. And then use

```
Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
canvas.drawBitmap(bit, draw_x, draw_y, null);
```

It will return the bitmap and draw that image...